# How to bind method into dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to bind a method into DropDownList using ASP.NET, C#.

I tried with this code:

```
public  DataTable gg()
    {
        DataTable _dt = new DataTable();
        _dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)));
        DataRow dr = _dt.NewRow();
        dr["Name"] = "jana";
        _dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        return _dt;
    }

<asp:DropDownList ID="sd" DataSource='<%#Eval("gg()")%>'  runat="server" />
```

It's not showing anything in the DropDownList control. 
Where is my error?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to *bind* the `gg()` method from code-behind in your `Page_Load` event. First your DropDownList control does not need a data source definition anymore:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="sd" runat="server" />
```

and in your code-behind-page (*.cs) in the [`Page_Load`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) event:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // specify the DataSource to use
    sd.DataSource = gg();
    // what field from the DataSource should be used for showing in the list
    sd.DataTextField = "Name";
    // what field from the DataSource should be used for saving (in this case the same)
    sd.DataValueField = "Name";
    // bind the control to the data source
    sd.DataBind();
}
```

An example could be found in MSDN [BaseDataBoundControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basedataboundcontrol.datasource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

If you want to use only the ASP.NET control then you can define an [ObjectDataSource object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9a4kyhcx%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) somewhere in your **aspx page** (for example just before the closing body tag):

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource
    id="ods1"
    runat="server"
    selectmethod="gg"
    typename="index" />
```

and tell it to use your `gg()` method (that you define in the code-behind) and bind the `ObjectDataSource` to the DropDownListControl:

```
<asp:DropDownList 
    ID="sd" 
    DataSourceId="ods1" 
    DataTextField="Name" 
    DataValueField="Name" 
    runat="server" />
```

Note, that you need to specify again the `DataTextField` and `DataValueField` properties of the DropDownList control.